# Standard/Correct way to create a singleton object with generic types

Tags: scala

I am trying to make a singleton object with generic types.

The object does not take generic types, so the following does not compile.

```
object SomeObj {
  val dataStore = mutable.HashMap.empty[K, V]

  def setPair[K, V](key: K, value: V): Option[V] = dataStore.set(key, value)

  def getValue[K, V](key: K): Option[V] = dataStore.get(key)
}
```

What would be the correct(standard way) to represent some sort of data store that is supposed to be only a single store shared by other program components?

Comment: do you know real `K` and `V` types when you define `SomeObj`?

Comment: K, V will be known only when the `setPair` or 'getValue` is invoked

Comment: So you want the data store to be a singleton even across multiple types? I.e. you could use the same key to get two different values if the values were of different types? What would you expect to happen if you asked for the value of a key using a supertype of the key’s type?

Comment: Only a single type pair at a time for the program lifetime.

Comment: Sounds like you want a class not an object, with the generic parameters on the class not the methods. Then your problem is just how to pass it around to achieve singleton behaviour.

Comment: Stateful singletons are not good practice in the functional paradigm, which I think is why this feels weird to me. If you really want to do it, you could have a companion object to your generic class which has a dictionary from type pairs (K, V) to instances of the class. Then you could ask it for a specific singleton dictionary. You'd have to fudge the typing a little, but it wouldn't be too bad. I would suggest trying to find a way to pass the instance around instead though.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, maybe it helps

import scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap

```
object Main {

  class Dict[K, V] {
    lazy val dictionary = Dictionary(new TrieMap[K, V]())

    def getDictionary(): TrieMap[K, V] = this.dictionary.values
  }

  case class Dictionary[K, V](val values: TrieMap[K, V])

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val dictionary = new Dict[String, String]()
    dictionary.getDictionary().put("one", "word")
    dictionary.getDictionary().foreach(println)
  }
}
```